# C# Calling edit command in ItemDataBound

Tags: c#, datalist, itemdatabound

I'm currently struggling to find the code which I need to call in the if statement in order to find the edit event of a data list.

I am trying to create a blank drop down item on an existing Drop Down List.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

```
protected void DL_Items_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ( )
    {
        DropDownList DDL_Designers = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DDL_Designers");
        DDL_Designers.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("N/A", "0"));
    }
}
```

Comment: if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)`

Answer (score 2):

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)
```